# Testing chained window methods with Jamine & Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a service in Angular which has a method to add a particular CSS class on the header when needed.

Here is a snippet of the service:

```
constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window) {}

  addHeaderClass() {
    const header = this.window.document.querySelector('header');

    if (!header?.classList.contains('games')) {
      header?.classList.add('games');
    }
  }
```

I am finding some difficulties to unit test the addHeaderClass.  Basically in the test I have this:

```
describe('Service: gaming-header.service.ts', () => {
  let windowSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<Window>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        GamingHeaderService,
        { provide: WINDOW, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('Window', []) },
      ],
    });

    windowSpy = TestBed.inject(WINDOW) as jasmine.SpyObj<Window>;
  });
```

I would like to create a test to make sure that the css class 'games' is added to the header tag when the addHeaderClass is called.  I tried to spy methods on the window object and also to mock but I can't find a way how to test this since all attempts are failing. I was able to test methods which are directly on the window object, but am having issues testing chained ones like `window.document.querySelector('header').classList.contains('games')`

Is there a way to do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, I would use the `window` object directly in the test and not mock it.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        GamingHeaderService,
        { provide: WINDOW, useValue: window },
      ],
    });
```

Even better, I would use Angular's `Renderer2` to add classes to elements and not rely on the window object.

Check out `Renderer2` and `addClass`. A blog post is [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-using-renderer2).

Comment: the only thing is that this case is a bit non-standard as the header tag is outside of the angular app.  Would I still be able to access such tag with renderer2 if it does not reside between the root angular app tags?

Comment: Also I was trying to mock rather than using the real Window in order not to pollute/change anything on the window object which might affect other tests.

Comment: You raise a good point about your 2nd point and I agree. And no, the renderer can only access the Angular app and not outside of it.